# Control number of HTML-Elements by value of input field

Tags: javascript, html, for-loop

I'm trying to build a JavaScript-based Layout grid generator where I want to control the number of grid rows by the value of an input field. E.g. if I type in `12`, my container-`div` should have 12 divs within. I already made a function that can handle this...

```
document.getElementById('numofrows').onkeyup=function(){
    var foo = [];
    for (var i=0; i<this.value ;i++) {
        foo[i] = document.createElement('div');
        container.appendChild(foo[i]);

    }
}
```

...But its drawback is, that every further input I make will add a number of divs again. How can I restrict the total number of child divs to what is just the actual value of the input field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can clear your children divs first, and then add the new list; like:

```
document.getElementById('numofrows').onkeyup = function () {
    var foo = [];

    // remove all the children of the parent element container
    while (container.firstChild) container.removeChild(container.firstChild);

    for (var i = 0; i < this.value; i++) {
        foo[i] = document.createElement('div');
        container.appendChild(foo[i]);

    }
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/IrvinDominin/56VeH/

Comment: Thank you very much! Works like a charme. I liked the other answers as well, but this one seems to be the cleanest.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to make it dynamic, every time the function executes, just clear the container div and add the number of divs corresponding to the input value. Like this:

```
document.getElementById('numofrows').onkeyup=function(){
    document.getElementById('container').innerHTML='';
    var foo = [];
    for (var i=0; i<this.value ;i++) {
        foo[i] = document.createElement('div');
        container.appendChild(foo[i]);

    }
}
```

Else a simple if else block should be fine for you.

Answer (score 1):

```
var maxNumber = this.value;
for (var i=0; i<maxNumber;i++)
```

just check the value BEFORE the for and not at every step

Answer (score 1):

This is not the best way to go about the problem, but.

```
if('div'.Count >= MaxNumber){
    Do Not Add Child.
}else{
    Add Child.    
}
```